# How to find current window size in pysimplegui

Tags: windows, size, font-size, pysimplegui

I want ask about code I can use to get my current pysimplegui window height and width.

I want use this code to adjust the text size of elements inside my window with increasing the window size.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Call reference - PySimpleGUI](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#window-the-window-object)

You can get the window size in pixel, (width, height), by `window.size`.

> size
>
> property: size
>
> Return the current size of the window in pixels
>
> | Type | Name | Meaning |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Tuple[(int), (int)] or Tuple[None, None] | return | (width, height) of the window |